# Time for an STM32 section?

Tags: discussion

I know the Arduino section was not successful but I see a lot of STM32 questions come by. I count ~30 in Electrical and ~60 on stack exchange in the last month. I have no idea at what frequency it makes sense.

Comment: What do you mean with a "section"?

Answer (score 7):

I'd say it doesn't make sense creating a site for just that microcontroller, all questions fit here (if good).

It's a useful tag though, and it's worth checking that all questions have it.